# Laravel Input array update with single submit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am updating a header amount with each header i am new to laravel please help below is my table, forms, view and controller update function code
[image: Table]
[image: Add Header Name]
[image: Add Header Amount]

**View Add Head Name**

```
div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
            <form action="/headers" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="">Header Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="header_name" required="required">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**View Add Head Amount**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
            <form action="/headers" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @foreach ($data as $header)
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="">Header Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="header_name[]" value="{{$header->header_name}}" required="required" readonly="readonly">
                            <input type="number" min="0" name="header_amount[]" placeholder="Amount" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1">
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Controller Function**

```
$count = Header::count();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
            {
                $header = Header::find($i);
                $header->header_amount = $request->input('header_amount');
                $header->save();
            }
            exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$count = Header::count();
$header = Header::find($i);

foreach ($header as $key => $detail) {
   $header->header_amount = $request->input('header_amount')[$key];
   $detail->save();
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: thanks got the logic from your code this works `$header = Header::all();
            foreach ($header as $key => $detail)
            {
                $detail->header_amount = $request->input('header_amount')[$key];
                $detail->save();
            }`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the header `ids[]` as a hidden input so that you don't have to initially get all of the `Header`'s which will mean one less query.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="{{ $header->id }}">
        <label for="">Header Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="header_name[]" value="{{$header->header_name}}" required="required" readonly="readonly">
        <input type="number" min="0" name="header_amount[]" value="{{ $header->header_amount }}" placeholder="Amount" required="required">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you could have something like:

```
$amounts = request('header_amount');

foreach (request('ids') as $key => $id) {
    Header::where('id', $id)->update(['header_amount' => $amounts[$key]]);
}
```

Comment: will try this great one less query

Answer (score 0):

Getting all data from headers table and using foreach loop to update each header row amount

```
$header = Header::all();
            foreach ($header as $key => $detail)
            {
                $detail->header_amount = $request->input('header_amount')[$key];
                $detail->save();
            }
            exit();
```

Comment: sure i added little explaination

Comment: Please explain what you need to change in the original code and why